# save output in data.frame for if-else statement

Tags: r, function

I try to create a function (which will be used later to work with shiny r).
at the moment i fail to store the results from my function in a data frame.
so far I have created the following code:

```
f_expccm <- function(n,h,m,rr,dr,mc,ac) {


for(i in 1:6) {

eccm[i]<- vector(length=1)

if(i==1){

  eccm[i] <- -ac
 print(eccm[i])


}
else{


x <- h*n
nm <- x*m
pc <- nm-mc 
crr <- 1*rr^(i-1)
cdr <- 1/(1+dr)^(i-1)

  eccm[i] <- pc*cdr*crr
 print(eccm[i])



}

output <- cbind(eccm[i])
 }

 }
  output
  qt <- f_expccm(10,250,.4,0.95,0.10,10,500)
```

I am expecting to get a output data.frame with the following entries:

```
  [1] -500
  [1] 855
  [1] 738.4091
  [1] 637.7169
  [1] 550.7555
  [1] 475.6525
```

however I am only able to get this if i add the print function (which to my knowledge does not save the results...):

Any help would greatly be appreciated!!!
Best regards,

Comment: When you use the return statement, the function exits!

Comment: thank you @Henrik, but when I remove that, the data frame (output) still remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the behavior you are looking for?

```
f_expccm <- function(n,h,m,rr,dr,mc,ac) {

  eccm <- vector(length=6)
  eccm[1] <- -ac

  for(i in 2:6) {   
    x <- h*n
    nm <- x*m
    pc <- nm-mc 
    crr <- 1*rr^(i-1)
    cdr <- 1/(1+dr)^(i-1)

    eccm[i] <- pc*cdr*crr
  }
   df <- data.frame(eccm)
   return(df)
}

> qt <- f_expccm(10,250,.4,0.95,0.10,10,500)
> qt
   eccm
1 -500.0000
2  855.0000
3  738.4091
4  637.7169
5  550.7555
6  475.6525
```

Comment: thank you. Yes this is it. However I would like to save the output directly as a data.frame - is this possible?
Ideally I would like to format this return(eccm) vector as a data.frame - is this possible?